# Click outside to leave the text editing without triggering any other clickable elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

Sometimes in the card we got title which can be clicked to edit, after edited we to leave the editing mode by blurring. However, there are a lot of clickable UI outside this text input, and I don't want them to be triggered. Simply apply `onBlur` event to leave editing mode cannot avoid triggering other components.

[image]

Here's my code which demonstrated this issue: ([CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/click-outside-to-leave-edit-mode-z7t1zd))

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const itemList = [
    { done: false, title: "1st task" },
    { done: false, title: "2nd task" },
    { done: true, title: "3rd task" }
  ];

  const [todoItemList, setTodoItemList] = useState(itemList);

  const rename = (newName, index) => {
    setTodoItemList(
      itemList.map((item, i) => {
        if (i === index) {
          item.title = newName;
        }
        return item;
      })
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {todoItemList.map((item, index) => (
        <TodoItem
          key={index}
          done={item.done}
          title={item.title}
          rename={(newName) => rename(newName, index)}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

const TodoItem = ({ done, title, rename }) => {
  const [isEdit, setIsEdit] = useState(false);

  const submit = (e) => {
    rename(e.target.value);
    setIsEdit(false);
  };

  const handleOnKeyUp = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      submit(e);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        border: "1px black solid",
        margin: "10px auto",
        padding: "5px 0"
      }}
    >
      <input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={done} />
      {isEdit ? (
        <input
          autoFocus
          type="text"
          defaultValue={title}
          onBlur={submit}
          onKeyUp={handleOnKeyUp}
        />
      ) : (
        <span onClick={() => setIsEdit(true)}>{title}</span>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Take the above one as an example, if you click on the "3rd task" to edit the title, and you try to leave edit mode, whether you can use enter key or click outside the text input. While you do the latter, trying to leave the edit mode of title 3, either clicking on other titles, or clicking on checkboxes, they are all triggered at the same time. If there's an overlay on the top to block all the possible clicks, then the original input text will be unclickable as well.

What I want to achieve is that when I was in the edit mode, any clicking outside the text input area does one thing: leave edit mode.
At the same time, the original text input should stay clickable (editable).
Can this be achievable? Does anyone have idea of how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a transparent div behind the input form that covers the viewport. That way you click on the div and it doesn't trigger any clicks.

Edit: As @sdym the OP noted, the `absolute`ly positioned div, now covers the input. So we also set the input's `z-index` property to raise it above the div.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/click-outside-to-leave-edit-mode-forked-2icfy6?file=/src/App.js:1457-1486)

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const itemList = [
    { done: false, title: "1st task" },
    { done: false, title: "2nd task" },
    { done: true, title: "3rd task" }
  ];

  const [todoItemList, setTodoItemList] = useState(itemList);

  const rename = (newName, index) => {
    setTodoItemList(
      itemList.map((item, i) => {
        if (i === index) {
          item.title = newName;
        }
        return item;
      })
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {todoItemList.map((item, index) => (
        <TodoItem
          key={index}
          done={item.done}
          title={item.title}
          rename={(newName) => rename(newName, index)}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

const TodoItem = ({ done, title, rename }) => {
  const [isEdit, setIsEdit] = useState(false);

  const submit = (e) => {
    rename(e.target.value);
    setIsEdit(false);
  };

  const handleOnKeyUp = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      submit(e);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        border: "1px black solid",
        margin: "10px auto",
        padding: "5px 0"
      }}
    >
      <input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={done} />
      {isEdit ? ( // jsx fragment in the line below
        <>
          <div
            style={{
              // this is the div
              position: "absolute",
              left: 0,
              top: 0,
              width: "100%",
              height: "100%"
            }}
          ></div>
          <input
            style={{
              position: "relative",
              zIndex: 1
            }}
            autoFocus
            type="text"
            defaultValue={title}
            onBlur={submit}
            onKeyUp={handleOnKeyUp}
          />
        </> // Close jsx fragment
      ) : (
        <span onClick={() => setIsEdit(true)}>{title}</span>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: While in this case, the selected text input would be unclickable. 
How can you fix this~?

Comment: I rephrase my question. I found I only mentioned that spec in my screenshot, sorry though.

Comment: @sdym No, you're absolutely right, and I should have considered that. To fix this, I set the `z-index` of  the selected input (also needed to set its position to `relative` for the z-index to apply). I updated the answer and the sandbox, and it should behave like you expect.

Comment: A good move! I always thought that if I want to put input ahead of the overlay, I should use `absolute`, and the layout would got messy afterward. Don't know that `relative` can work